# WSO2 API manager - how does publishing API works technically?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

WSO2 Documentation is not clear on how does the publishing of new API works.

Is is the publisher that pushes new API to the gateways ?
or
Is is the gateways that pulls or call new API configurations from the Manager ?
or
It is done through the database ?

And which protocol and ports does is uses ? An API Call, thrift, binairy ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things happening when you publish an API.

1) Persist API metadata in the database. Both the API Publisher and the API store pull these data from the database to display APIs.

2) Runtime artifact (i.e. Synapse file) is deployed in the gateway. This is done via a SOAP web service call. The API Publisher calls a SOAP web service exposed in the gateway for this.

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: Thanks you ! I just found this post that explains and give more details.
 https://medium.com/@chanakaudaya/understanding-wso2-api-manager-deployment-patterns-6faac8548f8d